# Docker service create freeze at preparation process

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --replicas 1 --publish published=1001, \
target=80 --name prismaccess_test_v1-release docker-repo.test.com/prismaccess_v1:release;
```

That command was working perfectly in the last weeked. But in this late morning when trying to create the service, the docker's operation is freezes with

```
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: new       [=====>                                             ]                                                                  overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: new       [=====>                                             ]
```

seems like it will hang forever. There are no any error from `docker service inspect`

```
docker service inspect prismaccess_v1-release
[
    {
        "ID": "xp57po72fnku7wz75561ph8ki",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 30474
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2020-11-30T08:38:10.657878468Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-11-30T08:38:10.657878468Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "prismaccess_v1-release",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "docker-repo.test.com/prismaccess_v1:release@sha256:116d436c4ae61a7278cdf4c0be06fde0f0b67c459ceeb0a175d1e556d21c775f",
                    "Init": false,
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 1001,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {}
        }
    }
]
```

docker service ps

```
docker service ps prismaccess_v1-release

ID                  NAME                              IMAGE                                                       NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE        ERROR               PORTS
l5nru6ouw3t7        prismaccess_v1-release.1   docker-repo.test.com/prismaccess_v1:release                       Running             New 17 minutes ago
```

and empty output for `docker service logs`

I've tried to re-create the service many times, unfortunately the result remains the same.

Really appreciate your help